# CSS Caching Issue in Magento

Tags: css, magento, caching

Basically on my Magento site after entering several lines of code in the custom css the theme breaks. I think this is due to a caching issue as when caching is turned off the theme also breaks. Also the main theme css file is large at 3400 lines approximately could this be an issue?

My CSS and JS Files are merged if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3400 lines of CSS code really matters. Why don't you create a separate files for CSS and JS.

Also in your custom.css file try to reduce the space and minimize the css file with this tool.

http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: Yes agree. create a separate file it's the way to go.